# generic iterators to access elements of vectors without using Templates c++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, vector, iterator

I am creating a function which should take as input iterators to vector
for example:

```
vector<int> a;
foo(a.begin(),a.end())
```

The `vector` can hold any type.

Now the simple way to do this is using templates

```
template <typename Iterator>
void foo(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
    for (Iterator it = first; it!=last; ++it) {
        cout << *it;
    }
}
```

I want to know if there is a way to achieve the same functionality without using templates. Since using Templates would force me to include these functions in Header file of a public API which I don't want to. So I wanted to know is there an alternate way to access the iterators without using Templates.

Comment: Do  you need the absolutely every type to be supported?

Comment: No. (this space intentionally left blank)

Comment: Mostly it should support vector <double>

Comment: Just take in a pair of `std::vector<double>::iterator`s then. You can't have your cake and eat it: either you choose the element type yourself, or you use a template to support them all.

Comment: A dirty way to go about this is to use void* pointers and pass the size of a single element. Still this would cause a problem as you don't know the type when u want to dereference the pointer. Which means you have to pass another variable to say what type of pointer u want to cast it to.... **This means that you cant support every data type**

Comment: "The vector can hold any type." "Mostly it should support vector <double>" Mostly? What should it do in the other 1% of cases? Make up your mind, it's either any type or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ways not to include the implementation in header files but they are not clean to implement (for instance you should know in advance the instantiations). Read here for more info about this issue:

- [Why can’t I separate the definition of my templates class from its declaration and put it inside a .cpp file?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl)
- [How can I avoid linker errors with my template functions?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#separate-template-fn-defn-from-decl)

For instance in:

## foo.h

```
#ifndef HI_
#define HI_

template<class Iterator>
void foo(Iterator first, Iterator last);

#endif
```

## foo.cpp

```
#include "stack.h"
using namespace std;


template<class Iterator>
void foo(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
    for (Iterator it = first; it != last; ++it) {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }
}

template
void foo( std::vector<int>::iterator  first,   std::vector<int>::iterator  last);

template
void foo( std::vector<double>::iterator  first,   std::vector<double>::iterator  last);
```

Now you can use `foo` function only for `double` and `int`. Other types won't link.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

This is a long answer.  The short answer is "type erasure"; go learn about it.

The long answer is two answers.  First I cover "do you just want to be able to iterate over contiguous `int`s?".  Then you want `span`.  This is a really simple form of type erasure that forgets what the exact container is you are working on so long as it is contiguous and over `T`.

The second answer is if you actually need to deal with multiple types (not just `int`) and multiple kinds of containers (not just contiguous ones).

The two answers are separated by a line.

---

The `span` concept (see [gsl::span](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL)) is designed for pretty much this reason.  It itself is a template (over the type you are working with), but it will be a concrete instance of a template in most interfaces.

Here is a toy version of it:

```
template<class T>
struct span_t {
  T* b = 0;
  T* e = 0;
  T* begin() const { return b; }
  T* end() const { return e; }
  span_t(span_t const&)=default;
  span_t& operator=(span_t const&)=default;
  span_t()=default;

  span_t( T* s, T* f ):b(s),e(f) {}
  span_t( T* s, std::size_t l):span_t(s, s+l){}
  template<std::size_t N>
  span_t( T(&arr)[N] ):span_t(arr, N) {}

  std::size_t size() const { return end()-begin(); }
  bool empty() const { return begin()==end(); }
  T& front() const { return *begin(); }
  T& back() const { return *(std::prev(end()); }
  T* data() const { return begin(); }

  span_t without_front( std::size_t N=1 ) const {
    return {std::next( begin(), (std::min)(N, size()) ), end()};
  }
  span_t without_back( std::size_t N=1 ) const {
    return {begin(), std::prev(end(), (std::min)(N, size()) )};
  }
};
```

we can augment it with conversion operators

```
namespace details {
  template<template<class...>class Z, class, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply:std::false_type{};
  template<class...>using void_t=void;
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z, void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...>:std::true_type{};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply = details::can_apply<Z,void,Ts...>;

template<class C>
using dot_data_r = decltype( std::declval<C>().data() );
template<class C>
using dot_size_r = decltype( std::declval<C>().size() );

template<class C>
using can_dot_data = can_apply< dot_data_r, C >;
template<class C>
using can_dot_size = can_apply< dot_size_r, C >;
```

`can_dot_data` detects via SFINAE if `.data()` is valid to do on an object of type `C`.

Now we add a constructor:

```
template<class T,
  std::enable_if_t<
    can_dot_data<T&>{}
    && can_dot_size<T&>{}
    && !std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, span_t>{}
    , int
  > =0
>
span_t( T&& t ): span_t( t.data(), t.size() ) {}
```

which covers `std::vector` and `std::string` and `std::array`.

Your function now looks like:

```
void foo(span_t<int> s) {
  for (auto&& e:s)
    std::cout << s;
  }
}
```

with use:

```
std::vector<int> a;
foo(a);
```

now, this only works for contiguous containers of a specific type.

---

Suppose this is not what you want.  Maybe you *do* need to solve this for a myriad of types, and you don't want to expose everything in the header.

Then what you need to do is known as type erasure.

You need to work out what minimal set of operations you need from the provided types.  Then you need to write wrappers that "type erase" these operations down to "typeless" operations.

This goes in the header, or in another helper header.

In the interface of the function, or in a header intermediate helper, you take the incoming types and do the type erasure, then pass the type-erased types into the "real" implementation.

An example of type erasure is `std::function`.  It takes almost anything that can be invoked with a fixed signature, and turns it into a single type-erased type.  Everything except how to copy, destroy and invoke an instance of the type is "forgotten" or erased.

For your case:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void foo(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
  for (Iterator it = first; it!=last; ++it) {
    cout << *it;
  }
}
```

I see two things that need to be erased down to; iteration, and printing.

```
struct printable_view_t {
  void const* data = 0;
  void(*print_f)(std::ostream& os, void const*) = 0;

  explicit operator bool()const{return data;}
  printable_view_t() = default;
  printable_view_t(printable_view_t const&) = default;

  template<class T,
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<T, printable_view_t>{}, int> =0
  >
  printable_view_t( T const& t ):
    data( std::addressof(t) ),
    print_f([](std::ostream& os, void const* pv){
      auto* pt = static_cast<T const*>(pv);
      os << *pt;
    })
  {}
  std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os)const {
    print_f(os, data);
    return os;
  }
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, printable_view_t p) {
    return p(os);
  }
};
```

`printable_view_t` is an example of type-erasing "I can be printed".

```
void bar( printable_view_t p ) {
  std::cout << p;
}

void test_bar() {
  bar(7);
  bar(3.14);
  bar(std::string("hello world"));
}
```

The next thing we'd have to do is type erase iteration.  This is harder, because we want to type erase iteration over iterating over a printable_view_t type.

Type erasing foreach is a tad easier, and often more efficient.

```
template<class View>
struct foreach_view_t {
  void* data = 0;
  void(*func)( std::function<void(View)>, void* ) = 0;

  explicit operator bool()const{return data;}
  foreach_view_t() = default;
  foreach_view_t(foreach_view_t const&) = default;

  template<class T,
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, foreach_view_t>{}, int> =0
  >
  foreach_view_t( T&& t ):
    data( const_cast<std::decay_t<T>*>(std::addressof(t)) ),
    func([](std::function<void(View)> f, void* pv){
      auto* pt = static_cast<std::remove_reference_t<T>*>(pv);
      for (auto&& e : *pt)
        f(decltype(e)(e));
    })
  {}
  void operator()(std::function<void(View)> f)const{
    func(f, data);
  }
};
```

we then daisy chain these together

```
void foo(foreach_view_t<printable_view_t> x) {
  x([](auto p){ std::cout << p; });
}
```

test code:

```
std::vector<int> a{1,2,3};

foo(a);
```

Now much of the header code was "hoisted" into the type erasure types instead of a function template body.  But careful choice of the points of type erasure can let you keep what you need from the types precise and narrow, and the logic of how you use those operations private.

As an example, the above code doesn't care *where* you are printing it to; `std::cout` was not part of the type erasure.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4e1dc388fa17614).

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know if there is a way to achieve the same functionality without using templates. [...] I wanted to know is there an alternate way to access the iterators without using Templates.

Yes, if you use C++14, but...

> Since using Templates would force me to include these functions in Header file of a public API which I don't want to.

... isn't a useful way for you because it's equivalent to use templates and you have to put it in the header file.

In C++14 you can use a lambda function with `auto` parameters.

```
auto foo = [](auto first, auto last)
 { for (auto it = first ; it != last; ++it ) std::cout << *it; };
```

The `auto`s aren't template (from a formal point of view) but are equivalent and you can't declare foo in the header and develop it in a `cpp` file.